# Error occured while EnableAssignToEmail in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am trying to set the `EnableAssignToEmail` property of SharePoint Task List to `YES`, so that assigned user gets an email after the task is being assigned to him/her. but I am getting an error as `An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`

```
**Additional information**: Method not found: 'Void
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List.set_EnableAssignToEmail(Boolean)".
```

I am using the latest version of CSOM DLL from the `nuget` packages.

```
using (ClientContext obj = new ClientContext("SharePOint site url")) {
    using (SecureString objSec = new SecureString())
    {
        foreach (var item in "PWD")
        {
            objSec.AppendChar(item);
        }
        obj.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("USERNAME", objSec);


        var list = obj.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Action");
        obj.Load(list);
        //obj.Load(list.EnableAssignToEmail);
        obj.ExecuteQuery();
        list.EnableAssignToEmail = true;
        obj.ExecuteQuery();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load list object again and do ExecuteQuery after changing EnableAssignToEmail property like below:

```
        string userName = "xxx@tenant.onmicrosoft.com";
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your password.");
        SecureString password = GetPassword();

        using (var clientContext = new ClientContext("https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"))
        {
            // SharePoint Online Credentials  
            clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, password);
            // Get the SharePoint web  
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            // Load the Web properties  
            clientContext.Load(web);
            // Execute the query to the server.  
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            // Web properties - Display the Title and URL for the web  
            List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("List1");
            list.EnableAssignToEmail = true;
            clientContext.Load(list);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
         }
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your approach but still getting the same error as An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.List.set_EnableAssignToEmail(Boolean)'. I am using "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client" version "16.1.0.0" which i downloaded with nuget package. Kindly let me know which version of your DLL. Thanks

Comment: I'm also using 16.1.0 CSOM got from Nuget Package, in this version dll, list.EnableAssignToEmail property is available.

Comment: the given code snippet throws the above-said error even before the execution of the code.

Comment: See my update capture, in my side, works as expected. Maybe you should debug your code.

Comment: which version of nuget package you are using?

Comment: The nuget package hosted in Visual Studio 2017 latest version.